# Flexibility of the hierarchy of module sources allowed in cabal project

Tags: haskell, build, module, hierarchy, cabal

I have a project with source tree:

```
src/
src/A/
src/A/A.hs
src/B/
src/B/C/
src/B/C/C.hs
...
```

The two haskell files divide source code into modules:

```
-- File A/A.hs
module A where
...
```

and

```
-- File B/C/C.hs
module B.C where
...
```

The cabal file contains:

```
other-modules: A, B.C, ...
hs-source-dirs: src/, src/A/, src/B/, src/B/C/, ...
```

But while the module `A` can be easily found, cabal complains about `B.C`:

```
cabal: can't find source for B/C in ...
```

I see no rational explanation why placing a file defining module `A` under `A/A.hs` is OK but placing `B.C` under `B/C/C.hs` isn't. Is there a workaround other than placing `C.hs` directly under `B` (I would like to maintain some separation of sources)?

Comment: Usually you only list top level dirs like `src/` in `hs-source-dirs`, then you will have to rename the module A => A.A and module B.C => B.C.C, also a module A would have to be placed in `src/A.hs` see for example [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.2.0/src/) as an example for a valid module structure. The error I think is because it looks for a folder B in the directory B/C/ and then a source file `C.hs` in there which is not there.

Comment: for a module X.Y.Z, GHC looks for the file X/Y/Z.hs in the hs-source-dirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that module B.C should be defined in file `B/C.hs`, not `B/C/C.hs` (that would be module `B.C.C`).  This error would have appeared if you had only one source dir with one source file, it is not because of the extra parts you have put in.

Also, the dir that appears in the `hs-source-dirs` directive should only be the root of the dir tree, so it is doubtful that you need all of the parts that you put in, for instance, `src/B/C` (which would treat `src/B/C` as another root....  meaning you can define top level modules in  that dir.  If you are actually doing that, I would consider this a mistake).

What you probably want to do is define multiple top level source dirs, like this

```
A_src/A.hs
B_src/B/C.hs

hs-source-dirs: A_src, B_src
```

Even better, I would suggest you use stack, which allows you to separate different modules completely with their own source dirs, called `src`, and independent .cabal files, allowing for richer dependencies between each module.

Comment: I am not sure I am ready to use `stack`. It feels completely unnatural when isolating a part of source in `A` from the rest of the code and then splitting it up into main part and some subparts to place the main part in `A/` and the subparts in say `A/A/`. I would really want to have a module that is self contained in one directory. Splitting into more trees is not what I am looking for, the logical separation is not that strict.

Comment: From your comment, it sort of sounds like what you really want to do is just put modules in different places in the source tree.  To do that, don't chance the hs-source-dirs (just use `src` alone), then put the modules in each subdir, and name them `<path>.<name>` (ie- create `B/C.hs`, then call it `B.C`).  When you create a source dir, everything recursively inside of it is considered for compiling.

Comment: well what I wanted and what I think makes sense: modules are in correspondence to directories (not path/filename.hs). but I already adopted the way you described. Thanks